# Angular 7 data update between unerealated pages

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am using `route.navigate` to go through pages, and I don't want to pass data in route params, because it is an object, or even array of items. But every time I try to set data in service and get automatically onInit when I get routed to another page I get undefined variable.

This shows, when I scan an item it automatically launches api to get that item data, and I want to pass that data to a page that is routed to

```
this.inv.getInvItems(this.itemKey).subscribe(data =>{        
        this.inv.setInvItem(data);
        this.router.navigate(['/itemTake']);  })
```

after this code it reroutes to item take

and setInvItem looks like this

```
setInvItem(data){
      this.invItem = data;
  }
```

but when I go to other page and trying to get that set data from same service it is undefined

```
console.log(this.inv.invItem);
```

any ideas? advices?
Pages are not child/parent type, it doesn't stay in same space it gets rerouted

App is being made in newest angular 7 cli

Comment: Please copy the code in the question directly, that will help us help you.

Comment: Please edit your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)  for details. Thank you.

Comment: As for your question, it looks like your components might have different instances of the `inv`, whatever that is. Please post all the relevant methods (getItems, setItems, and the item itself) and the parts in components where you call them.

Comment: well i tried doing singleton service, but it get f up in the process and doesnt compile any more

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of killing all my brain cells for not knowing this answer, now everything works fine, just for some reason it was cached or something, needed to launch on incognito and everything worked just fine

Comment: To disable caching completely, have your developer tools console open. Click the Network Tab and check the "Disable Cache" checkbox ;)